# Discord for partially decohered bell state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, information

To illustrate discord and its use, [Zurek in his paper on discord](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0105072.pdf) (NB pdf) gives example of a partially decohered bell state i.e. 
$$\rho_{AB}=\frac{1}{2}(|00\rangle\langle 00|+|11\rangle\langle 11|) + \frac{z}{2}(|00\rangle \langle 11|+|11\rangle \langle 00|)$$
using the measurement basis for Alice's side.
$$\{\cos\theta |0\rangle + e^{i\phi} \sin\theta |1\rangle,\ e^{-i\phi} \sin\theta |0\rangle + \cos\theta |1\rangle\}$$
He plotted it in the [Fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDPtJ.png).

Now my problem is that I have not been able to reproduce this result. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Cie.jpg) is what I got. I can not seem to locate what could be the source problem. The Mathematica code which I used is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B39rxnxwFcLiZUZoSkdKNFJabFE/edit?usp=sharing). Can anyone see what might be going wrong here.

Comment: Your state $\psi_{AB}$ is not the same as Zurek's partially decohered Bell state in Eq. (17). (In particular, the latter is a mixed state.)

Comment: @Norbert Sorry I wrote it wrong, but you can see in mathematica code that I used it correctly. Thanks I'll correct it now.

Comment: The Mathematica code cannot be viewed without requesting some kind of permission.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I have changed it's privacy please. this works now. I checked it by signing out. please try it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have **confirmed with Zurek**, he told me that it was wrong (at least the period-wise) and it has been pointed out many times by other people including Animesh Dutta.

Comment: Could you provide references to, at least, the other rebuttals?